# How to delete all dots and number after dots with Vim

Tags: vim

UPDATED

I scan a page and I have many lines with dots and numbers like the followings. Due to scan, the numbers are very irregular. There can be space(s) or dot between numbers.

```
g. Problem-Solving Strategy: Use Logical Reasoning .........................1. 3
h. Problem-Solving Strategy: Use a Venn Diagram ..............................1 4
i. Review: Problem-Solving Strategies .................................... 1 5
(and more lines)
a. Scientific Notation ............................................... 2. 1 -22
b. Variable Expressions .................................................. .24 -26
c. Functions ....................................................................3.  8-39
```

Now I want to edit this without dots and numbers after dots like this with vim.

```
g. Problem-Solving Strategy: Use Logical Reasoning
h. Problem-Solving Strategy: Use a Venn Diagram 
i. Review: Problem-Solving Strategies 
(and more lines)
a. Scientific Notation 
b. Variable Expressions 
c. Functions
```

At the moment I am doing it line by line and it takes a lot of time.

I am wondering if there is a better and shorter way to do it with VIM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the trailing stuff with a simple substitution, anchored to the end of the line (`$`), that replaces optional whitespace, dots, optional whitespace, and a number with nothing:

```
:%s/\s*\.\+\s*\d\+$//
```

Because the number stuff seems to be pretty irregular (based on your example), we need to be more lenient at the end. For this, I've used a collection with named groups; `[:space:]` is equivalent to `\s` (but can be used in a `[...]` collection).

```
:%s/\s*\.\+[-.[:digit:][:space:]]\+$/
```

Comment: Isn't `:%s/[-.[:digit:][:space:]]\+$` enough?

Comment: @Tassos That depends on the existing data; your proposal would also remove stuff like `-   12312     123123` that doesn't contain dots at all.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
:%norm / \ze\.\.^MD<CR>      ^M is Ctrl+V followed by Enter
```

Or with a substitution:

```
:%s/\zs \.\..*<CR>
```

Comment: Why the use `/zs` as it looks like they are trying to remove the tailing space as well?

Comment: @PeterRincker: no reason beside sloppy thinking. I added it in an attempt to disambiguate the pattern but yeah, that's not needed.